# Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Storage Version 9.3.0.0 (.Net Standard) works fine in the .NetCore Application but throws an error in .NetFramework Project

Tags: c#, azure

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the correct Version of .NET Framework or .NET Core when we reference .NET Standard project.

Below chart shows the corresponding version in Framework, Core and Standard.

[image]

Note that if the project is multi-objective oriented, the referenced class library also supports multi-objective oriented frameworks when referring to the class library.

More information for your reference: [.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)